# Flutter: CupertinoNavigationBar with leading icon and title

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

how can I create in Flutter a leading item of Navigation bar with back icon and title of the previous scaffold. Have a look in a picture:

[image]

I've tried to put a `Text` widget inside a `Row` but got an overflow.

```
CupertinoNavigationBar(
    middle: Text('New report'),
    leading: Align(
      alignment: Alignment(-1.5, -1),
      child: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        icon: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              CupertinoIcons.left_chevron,
              color: CupertinoColors.destructiveRed,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your leading could be a Row containing the Icon and the text: Something like that:

```
CupertinoNavigationBar(
    middle: Text('New report'),
    leading: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              CupertinoIcons.left_chevron,
              color: CupertinoColors.destructiveRed,
            ),
             Text('Reports')
             ],
        ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Have you read my comment about Text widget inside a Row? This approach doesn’t work

Comment: I tested my snippet before posting here and it worked exactly as you expected. You should be more polite with people that are trying to help you

Answer (score 0):

Now in `CupertinoNavigationBar` when we give Back action on Bar we also have to provide action to it.
This is my working snippet.

You can see that we have to provide IconButton which is Clickable.

```
return CupertinoPageScaffold(
  navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
    leading: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.chevron_back),
          color: theme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        )
      ],
    ),
    middle: Text(
      'Second Route',
      style: textStyle,
    ),
    backgroundColor: theme.colorScheme.primary,
  ),
  child: Center(
    child: CupertinoButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: const Text('Go back!'),
    ),
  ),
);
```